# Textures created with Photoshop show up with a white border

Tags: opengl, libgdx, textures, graphics

All of a sudden, I started having this problem. I've used libGDX + Photoshop before and never had this problem. One of my textures is showing up with a white border/glow around.

[image]

The texture is the black blob on the middle, which is a 256 pixels png with a few black brushstrokes I created with Photoshop, just to test it.

Everything in libGDX is on default. I haven't changed the blending function, I'm just using a SpriteBatch to render the image without any changes.

The weird thing is, some other textures I created with Photoshop, same size, RBG 8 bit color mode (just like my blob image), look fine. These are temporary textures I created by downloading a png from the web, pasting it into Photoshop, applying a solid color overlay effect to it and saving it back as a png.

Any idea what's causing this?

Edit: Here's how I'm loading my textures:

```
private static Texture createTexture(String fileName, boolean maxQuality, Texture.TextureWrap textureWrap) {
    Texture result = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(fileName), true);
    result.setFilter(maxQuality ? Texture.TextureFilter.MipMapLinearLinear : Texture.TextureFilter.MipMapLinearNearest, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear); // TODO: Are these the best?
    if(textureWrap != null)
        result.setWrap(textureWrap, textureWrap);
    return result;
}

texture = new TextureRegion(createTexture("data/blob.png"));
```

I just found out using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28409950/1219414) that the transparent pixels in my texture are white (1, 1, 1, 0). So I'm pretty sure the cause is a combination of this, the linear resizing and probably the blending function. Not sure what's the right way to fix it though. Don't want to change the resizing to nearest.

Comment: Is the texture coming from a packed spritesheet? Are you using a `TextureAtlas`?

Comment: Probably because you have some alpha blending pixels at the edge of your sprite.

Comment: @bornander No atlas. See my edit.

Comment: Change the pixels to 0,0,0,0. When additive blending is used- the white pixels will be added to the background and result in that white border.

Answer (score 2):

So I figured it out and found a couple of ways to solve it.

**Cause:**

Photoshop, for some reason, will produce white transparent pixels. And when libGDX resizes the pictures it seems to average the pixels, so if a pixel is {1, 1, 1, 0} (transparent white) and another is {1, 0, 0, 1} (red), the average would be {1, .5, .5, .5}, which is a semi transparent mix of white and red and looks whitish on a dark background:

[image: white borders]

**Solution 1:**

One way is to premultiply the image, which turns transparent pixels black, using Texture Packer or some other program. This solves the white border on a dark background problem:

[image]

But it'll create another problem when using a bright background. Since the default blending functions are `GL_SRC_ALPHA` and `GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA`, which tells OpenGL to multiply the source image's value times its alpha and add it to the background's value times one minus the source's alpha, blending a mix or red and transparent black caused by image resizing {.5, 0, 0, .5} with a white background {1, 1, 1, 1} will produce {.75, .5, .5, .75}, which is a mix of red, black and white, and looks like a dark border around the texture:

[image: premultiplied GL_SRC_ALPHA]

The solution here is to change the blending functions to `GL_ONE` and `GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA` (using `setBlendFunction` is you're using a `SpriteBatch`). This tells OpenGL to multiply the source's value by one, which will produce {1, .5, .5, 1}, an actual mix of red and white, when blending the mix of red and transparent black {.5, 0, 0, .5} with the white background {1, 1, 1, 1}:

[image: premultiplied GL_ONE]

**Solution 2:**

What I ended up doing is using Texture Packer to reduce border artifacts. This will replace each transparent pixel with the color of a neighbor non-transparent pixel and will work fine with the default blending function on any background.

The reason I used this solution is simply because I already use the default blending mode on every other place. I guess the way to go is to pick one solution and stick to it.